# Pendulum simulation

Tags: python, pygame, physics, physics-engine

I am trying to write simple pendulum simulation in Pygame. The point is that I am trying to simulate directly the forces on the pendulum (gravity and tension) rather than solving the differential equation that describes the motion. First I wrote a function that get a vector, rotate the axis-system by some angle, and return this vector's components in the new, rotated axis-system; the code of this function is fine and it works as expected.

Each tick of the simulation I rotate the gravity vector by the angle between the pendulum and the rope, and get the new components - one in the direction of the rope, and one is orthogonal to it. the tension the and component in the direction of the rope cancelling each other, so only the orthogonal component is important. After I calculate it, I rotate the acceleration vector back to the normal coordinates system, and integrate. However, the resulting behavior is not as intended. What can be the reason?

This is the code:

```
from __future__ import division
import copy
import pygame
import random
import math
import numpy as np
import time

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
size = (width, height) = (600,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

def rotate(vector,theta):
    #rotate the vector by theta radians around the x-axis
    Vx,Vy = vector[0],vector[1]
    cos,sin = math.cos(theta),math.sin(theta)
    newX,newY = Vx*cos-Vy*sin, Vy*cos+Vx*sin #the newX axis is the result of rotating x axis by theta
    return [newX,newY]

class pendulum:
    def __init__(self,x,y,x0,y0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0
        self.velocity = [0,0]
        self.a= [0,0]
        self.angle = 0
    def CalcForce(self):
        self.angle = math.atan2(-(self.y-self.y0),self.x-self.x0)
        gravity = rotate(g,self.angle)
        self.a[1]=gravity[1]
        self.a[0] = 0 #This component is cancelled by the tension
        self.a = rotate(self.a,-self.angle)
    def move(self):
       #print pylab.dot(self.velocity,[self.x-self.x0,self.y-self.y0])
        self.velocity[0]+=self.a[0]
        self.velocity[1]+=self.a[1]
        self.x+=self.velocity[0]
        self.y+=self.velocity[1]
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x0,self.y0), 5)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x0,self.y0), (int(self.x), int(self.y)),3)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,255), (int(self.x),int(self.y)), 14,0)
g = [0,0.4]
p = pendulum(350,100,300,20)

while 1:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    p.CalcForce()
    p.move()
    p.draw()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Thank you.

Comment: What unexpected behavior are your seeing?

Comment: The movement is not a periodic movement.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but I see you are using ints instead of floats for your vectors. That can cause issues.

Comment: You are still solving the differential equation by numerical integration :)

Comment: By the way, you assume that tension cancels the radial component of the gravity. This is only true at both extreme points where the bob is not moving. At any point where the bob is moving, the tension is higher than the radial gravity component and the difference is the centripetal force. Without it the bob won't be following a circular trajectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems here.  I'll fix a few and leave a few for you.

What I fixed was: 1) since you've imported numpy, you should use it, and write things in terms of the vectors; 2) it's an unreasonable demand on yourself to write everything and have it work immediately; so you need to plot intermediate results, etc, like here I plot `a` as well, so you can see whether it makes sense; 3) your whole "rotation" approach is confusing; instead think of component parts; which I calculate here directly (it's shorter, easier to read and understand, etc); 4) in all simulations where you use a time step, you should explicitly use dt so you can change the timestep without changing other parameters.

Now if you watch it you can see it looks almost reasonable.  Notice though that the acceleration never goes upward, so the ball just falls while it oscillates.  The reason for this is that you did not include the tension of the rope into the forces on the ball.  I'll leave that part to you.

```
import pygame
import math
import numpy as np

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
size = (width, height) = (600,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


class pendulum:
    def __init__(self,x,y,x0,y0):
        self.x0 = np.array((x0, y0))
        self.x = np.array((x, y), dtype=float)
        self.v = np.zeros((2,), dtype=float)
        self.a = np.zeros((2,), dtype=float)
    def CalcForce(self):
        dx = self.x0 - self.x
        angle = math.atan2(-dx[0], dx[1])
        a = g[1]*math.sin(angle)  # tangential accelation due to gravity
        self.a[0] = at*math.cos(angle)
        self.a[1] = at*math.sin(angle)
    def move(self):
        #print np.dot(self.a, self.x-self.x0) #is a perp to string?
        self.x += dt*self.v
        self.v += dt*self.a
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,0), self.x0, 5)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), self.x0, self.x.astype(int),3)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,255), self.x.astype(int), 14,0)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), (self.x+200*self.a).astype(int), self.x.astype(int), 4)
dt = .001
g = [0,0.4]
p = pendulum(350,100,300,20)

while 1:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    for i in range(100): # don't plot every timestep
        p.CalcForce()
        p.move()
        p.draw()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Happy to help.  It's worth pointing out that your approach is valid, but a bit more difficult than the standard simulation.  That is, you need an equation for the dynamics of the system, but which to use?  The standard approach is to work a bit on the math to describe the system in terms of \theta, which has the constant length assumption built in.  Your approach will require including the forces from the tension on the string, which is interesting, but more difficult.  (For the standard approach, google it, don't use the Lagrangian, as BenDundee suggested, which is very advanced.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a simulation, I think you're doing it the hard way. I'd start with the equation of motion, see [Equation 20](http://www.engr.iupui.edu/~skoskie/ECE680/ECE680_l3notes.pdf), here. The dots mean differentiate with respect to time---so the equation is `d^2/dt^2 \theta = ...` Then you should implement a finite differences scheme in the time direction, and step through time. At each step (label with `i`), you can calculate the x and y coordinates of the bob, based on the length of the pendulum and `\theta_i`. Check out the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method) on finite differences.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but as I said, my aim is not to solve the differential equation that describes the movement.

Comment: You don't need to solve it. You're using it to give you the motion.